# Pattern.matches() against a char array without cast to String in java

Tags: java, arrays, regex, char

### Scenario

I need to check a regex pattern against a character array (`char[]`). I am not allowed to cast the character array to a String, because of security considerations. Java's Pattern.matches() method is designed to take a pattern and a String. Also, the regex pattern is passed to me from another source, and will change (is not constant).

This does not work:

```java
// This pattern comes from another source, that I do not control. It may change.
String pattern = "^(.)\\1+$"; 

char[] exampleArray = new char[4];
    exampleArray[0] = 'b';
    exampleArray[1] = 'l';
    exampleArray[2] = 'a';
    exampleArray[3] = 'h';

// This should return true, for this pattern, but I cannot pass in a char[].
boolean matches = Pattern.matches(pattern, exampleArray);
```

### Thoughts

I attempted to deconstruct the regex pattern and examine the array for each part of the pattern, but the conditional logic required to interpret each part of the pattern thwarted me. For example: Suppose the pattern contains something like `"(.){5,10}"`. Then I only need to check the `char[]` length. However, if it contains `"^B(.){5,10}X"`, then I need to do something very different. It feels like there are too many possibilities to effectively deconstruct the regex pattern and account for each possibility (which is exactly why I've always just used `Pattern.matches()`).

### Question

What would be the most efficient way of checking a regex pattern against a character array without casting the character array to a String, or creating a String?

Comment: What makes you think that the `char[]` isn't already in the heap?

Comment: Good point, and maybe bad wording on my part. This is more of a security best practice, for password validation. The presence/absence on the heap isn't the driver behind the requirement. I've updated my question.

Comment: Here is an example of why I am required to avoid using a String:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/use-char-array-string-storing-passwords-java/

Comment: I'm aware. Are you allowed to use a `StringBuilder`? If so, you can use the overloaded [`Pattern#matches`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#matches(java.lang.String,java.lang.CharSequence)), and then invoke `StringBuilder#setLength` with a length of `0` to clear it.

Comment: I'd up-vote your comment here if I could @JacobG. , since you sent me in the right direction. Thanks for the quick response and thoughts! Going to circle back to my tech-lead with this option, and the `CharBuffer` option below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pattern.matches accepts a general CharSequence. You can use for example CharBuffer from java.nio instead of String.

```
boolean matches = Pattern.matches(pattern, CharBuffer.wrap(exampleArray));
```

CharBuffer.wrap will not create an extra copy of the password in memory, so of all the options it's the safest.

Comment: Yup, that's better

Answer (score 4):

If someone has access to the machine's memory then the problems can get far beyond the uncovering of passwords.

`boolean matches = Pattern.matches(pattern, new String(exampleArray));`

Comment: While I agree, the requirement is still on me. Also, I am explicitly trying to avoid the cast to a String.

Comment: There's no cast, at the end of the day a String *is* a sequence of characters.

Comment: For certain. Technically, you're correct. You aren't casting to a String, but the requirement is based on avoiding the creation of a String object at all, and what you have here creates a string. I'll update my question to be more specific.