# How to replace Char Sequence in a char array without converting it to String in java

Tags: java, arrays, regex, replace, char

Given a char[], need to replace a char sequence in the char[] with empty String. I am doing it by converting char[] to string and using replace method to achieve it. But I need to avoid converting char[] to String as this has sensitive data.
How to replace it in the char[] without converting to String?

Current code,

```
char[] chars = charArray;
String str = String.valueOf(chars)
                        .replaceAll("(.*?)-----", "")
                        .replaceAll("\\s", "");
```

Comment: Unless you wanna do the pattern matching yourself on the `char[]`, take a look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60977992/pattern-matches-against-a-char-array-without-cast-to-string-in-java

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pattern.matches() against a char array without cast to String in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60977992/pattern-matches-against-a-char-array-without-cast-to-string-in-java)

Comment: boolean matches = Pattern.matches(pattern, CharBuffer.wrap(exampleArray));
will just check if it is present, i need to replace also.

Comment: What problem are you having doing the replace?

Comment: string.replaceAll works perfectly fine. just that I am working with sensitive data so i shouldn't be using the String, but should be using char[]. Now my question is how can i do replaceAll on char[].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `Matcher` accepts a `CharBuffer` which you can easily get with `CharBuffer.wrap(chars)`. For the output, you can use a `StringBuilder` which internally does not use strings. When you are done processing, you can get the characters out with the `getChars(...)` method.

```java
char[] chars = {'a','b','c','d','-','-','-','-','-','e','f','g','h'};

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*?)-----");
Matcher m = p.matcher(CharBuffer.wrap(chars));

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while (m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(sb, "");
}
m.appendTail(sb);

chars = new char[sb.length()];
sb.getChars(0, sb.length(), chars, 0);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(chars)); // output: [e, f, g, h]
```